# how to use forEach() on nested objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, nested, javascript-objects

I'm working on a browser quiz project. I have made an array of objects that has the question choices nested in a further object. I'm struggling to figure out how to compare the users choice of the 4 options to the correct answer in the answers array.

I'm stuck because I don't know how to use for each on nested objects inside an array.

```
const list = document.createElement('ol');
const li1 = document.createElement('li');
const li2 = document.createElement('li');
const li3 = document.createElement('li');
const li4 = document.createElement('li');

const choices = document.querySelector('.choices');

choices.appendChild(list);
list.appendChild(li1);
list.appendChild(li2);
list.appendChild(li3);
list.appendChild(li4);

const possibleAnswers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'];

const questionPool = [
    {
        questionOne:
            {
                answers:
                    {
                        answerOne: li1,
                        answerTwo: li2,
                        answerThree: li3,
                        answerFour: li4
                    }
            }
    },
    {
        questionTwo:
            {
                answers:
                    {
                        answerOne: li1,
                        answerTwo: li2,
                        answerThree: li3,
                        answerFour: li4
                    }
            }
    },
    {
        questionThree:
            {
                answers:
                    {
                        answerOne: li1,
                        answerTwo: li2,
                        answerThree: li3,
                        answerFour: li4
                    }
            }
    },
    {
        questionFour:
            {
                answers:
                    {
                        answerOne: li1,
                        answerTwo: li2,
                        answerThree: li3,
                        answerFour: li4
                    }
            }
    },
    {
        questionFive:
            {
                answers:
                    {
                        answerOne: li1,
                        answerTwo: li2,
                        answerThree: li3,
                        answerFour: li4
                    }
            }
    },
    {
        questionSix:
            {
                answers:
                    {
                        answerOne: li1,
                        answerTwo: li2,
                        answerThree: li3,
                        answerFour: li4
                    }
            }
    },
    {
        questionSeven:
            {
                answers:
                    {
                        answerOne: li1,
                        answerTwo: li2,
                        answerThree: li3,
                        answerFour: li4
                    }
            }
    }
];
```

Comment: Can you simplify your `questionPool` array, by using the array index as a marker of the order of your questions? That way, all of your array elements would have the same structure - `{ "answers" : { "answerOne" : "...", "answerTwo" : "...", ...} }` and it would be easier to loop. In case it's unclear what I'm suggesting, take a look at [this](https://i.imgur.com/N6cHHLj.png). With this setup, `questionPool[0]` would refer to the first question, `questionPool[1]` to the second, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly I think this answer might help you;

1. You have to change the structure of your object to make it universal.
2. You can go through your object array in which each object refers to the object of the 4 answers.
3. Loop to access the 4 possible answers.

This is how I would do it:

```
var list = document.createElement("ol");
        var li1 = document.createElement("li");
        var li2 = document.createElement("li");
        var li3 = document.createElement("li");
        var li4 = document.createElement("li");

        let choices = document.querySelector(".choices")

        choices.appendChild(list)
        list.appendChild(li1)
        list.appendChild(li2)
        list.appendChild(li3)
        list.appendChild(li4)

        let questionPool = [
            {
                answers: {
                    1: li1,
                    2: li2,
                    3: li3,
                    4: li4
                }
            },
            {
                answers: {
                    1: li1,
                    2: li2,
                    3: li3,
                    4: li4
                }
            },
            {
                answers: {
                    1: li1,
                    2: li2,
                    3: li3,
                    4: li4
                }
            }
        ];

        questionPool.forEach(element => {
            for(const item in element.answers){
                //here you have access to the 4 li
                console.log(element.answers[item]);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks , this is really helpful but I still don't get how to write the comparison. The for loop will iterate through the objects, I think I  get that, but I don't get what to put in the code block. I would try an if else statement but as I try to write it I'm not sure how to. I haven't come across the item or in keywords, or learned how to do arrow functions. Could you help me with the next part please?

Comment: To write the comparison you must actually use a condition when the user clicks on a button for example.
I recommend you: 
[Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener?retiredLocale=de)

Comment: [condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else?retiredLocale=de)
[Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: I've made some changes with everyones suggestions but i've hit a wall again. Don't know if this should be a new post but ill remove it if so. I have no idea how to change the display from the start page to the questions and i can't keep up with the improving the logic if i can't figure out how to change what's displayed. Could you give me a hint please on what keywords or process i'd need to lookup to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to refactor your code beacause most of it was repetitions for no reason, more details in the comments :

```js
const questionEl = document.createElement('span')
const list = document.createElement("ol");
const nextBtn = document.createElement('button')

const choicesEl = document.querySelector(".choices")

nextBtn.textContent = 'Next'

choicesEl.appendChild(questionEl)
choicesEl.appendChild(list)
choicesEl.appendChild(nextBtn)

// Store you list elements by span (text of the answer) and radio (input field)
const listElements = Array.from({ length: 4 }).map(i => {
    const li = document.createElement('li')
    const radio = document.createElement('input')
    const span = document.createElement('span')

    radio.type = 'radio'
    radio.name = 'quiz-radio'

    li.appendChild(radio)
    li.appendChild(span)
    list.appendChild(li)

    // for convenience
    span.onclick = () => radio.click()

    return { radio, span }
})

// use arrays instead of objects
const questionsPool = [
    {
        question: 'What is the formula for water ?',
        right: 0,
        answers: [
            'H2O',
            'NH3',
            'CO2',
            'C6H12O6',
        ]
    }, {
        question: 'What color is the sky ?',
        right: 1,
        answers: [
            'blue',
            'skyblue',
            'lightblue',
            'navyblue',
        ]
    }
]

let score = 0
let questionIndex = 0

// update the texts in the spans
const updateQuestion = () => {
    const { question, answers } = questionsPool[questionIndex]

    questionEl.textContent = question

    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        listElements[i].span.textContent = answers[i]
}

// inital rendering
updateQuestion()

nextBtn.onclick = () => {
    // if the user selected the right answer : increment his score
    if (listElements[questionsPool[questionIndex].right].radio.checked) score++
    
    
    // if there is remaining question
    if (questionIndex + 1 < questionsPool.length) {
        // go to the next one and update texts
        questionIndex++
        updateQuestion()
    }
    
    else
        // show the final user score
        console.log({ score })
}
```

```html
<div class="choices"></div>
```

Hope it helped you !